# How to detect the deleted data entry in Orchard cms Database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I have created a module in Orchard cms, in which I created a form to collect the data and also added a image field(media). Now I have created a separate view(.chtml) to display the list of data that are collected from form in module in admin section.
Now suppose I added few data, let it be two entry in the form and I display all the two entry in newly created separate view. But When I delete the one of entry in form in admin section, it deleted and disappear there, but it is still present in database and visible in my newly created separate view. Can anyone please help me to know, how to detect the delete entry in Orchard Cms Database. I think it is soft deleted, because it is still in database but not showing in admin view section (dashboard).

Comment: Did you try the Version Manager module?

Comment: I dont know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Orchard always does soft deletes on content items. There are two boolean flags - `Published` and `Latest` - kept in table `Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord` for each version. If both are false, the version is considered deleted. If there is no published and latest version for a given item, the whole item is considered deleted.

If a deleted item still appears in your custom view, you're probably doing some custom query in your code and you may need to revisit it. `ContentManager` fetches published versions by default (`Get` and `Query` methods) only.